# ¿Cómo saber cuando un número existe entre dos puntos?

Tags: java, regex

Mi problemática es que quiero saber cuando esto exista `2.2.2` o esto `2.2.`, cuando haya más de un punto en la cifra me debería de avisar el programa de java y ahorita lo estoy haciendo de una forma sencilla:

```
value.contains("..") && contaPunto==0
```

Pero aquí hay un problema, ya que si los puntos no van juntos me sigue aceptando cifras con varios puntos.

Por eso quisiera saber si hay alguna forma de que con REGEX se pudiera saber si hay más de un punto en la cifra.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> un número existe entre dos puntos?

Simplemente se debe coincidir con un punto, 1 o más dígitos, y otro punto:

```
\.\d+\.
```

Código:

```
import java.util.regex.Pattern;
```

```
String texto= "2.2.2";

if (Pattern.compile("\\.\\d+\\.").matcher(texto).find()) {
    //tiene 1 número entre 2 puntos
}
```

---

> saber si hay más de un punto en la cifra

Esto es una pregunta diferente! También aplica a casos como `1..2`, `x 3.4. Y`, o `4...`. Para coincidir con esto, tenemos que ver que se cumplan las 2 condiciones por separado:

- cualquier cantidad de puntos, y tiene al menos un dígito: `\.*\d`.
- cualquier cantidad de dígitos, y 1 punto, repetido 2 veces: `(?:\d*\.){2}`.

Y para combinar ambas condiciones usamos una [inspección positiva](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html#special) ([*lookahead*](https://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html)):

```
(?=\.*\d)(?:\d*\.){2}
```

Código:

```
import java.util.regex.Matcher;
import java.util.regex.Pattern;
```

```
final String texto = "2.2.3";
final String regex = "(?=\\.*\\d)(?:\\d*\\.){2}";

final Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(regex);
final Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(texto);

if (matcher.find()) {
    //hay más de un punto en la cifra
}
```

Answer (score 0):

> Por eso quisiera saber si hay alguna forma de que con REGEX se pudiera
>   saber si hay mas de un punto en la cifra.

Si necesitas una expresion regular para validar que un texto contenga mas de un punto, entonces podrías utilizar:

```
str.matches(".*\\..*\\..*")
```

Donde basicamente la expresion busca cualquier cadena de 0 o mas caracteres entre 2 puntos literales.

Si lo que quieres en cambio es validar que un numero es un decimal valido, entonces la expresion deberia forzar solo digitos y solo un punto en una posicion intermedia:

```
str.matches("\\d+(\\.\\d+)?")
```